# Does anyone recognize this debug connector?

Tags: debugging, interface, breakout

I'm looking at a board with this debug interface and I would like to know what it is so I can consider it in future designs. The scale below is 1 mm gradient.

It looks like something off the shelf that I've seen before. There is also a Tag-Connect interface elsewhere on the device so I wouldn't be surprised if this too was COTS in some way.

Anyone recognize it?

[image]

Comment: That's an awfully fine pitch for pogo pins. I wonder if it's an unused BGA connector footprint.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany Thats what I was thinking. Especially since they have been tinned. If it was meant for pogo pins they would likely have been kept bare. The Tag-Connect I mentioned is not tinned at all. But its definitely wired as a JTAG interface at the very least so I'm guessing it is an external connector.